# Why absolute element does not keep position when parent scroll

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrap {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in snippet. When I scroll the `.wrap`, the `.absolute` also go away too. Why this happen. And how can I keep the `.absolute` on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `position: sticky;`, like so:

```css
.wrap {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

.absolute {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
</div>
```

For a broader explanation on the why, you may read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) article about positioning.